# Getting "ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser'" with bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm on windows 10 using python **3.8.2** and got this problem when I try to run `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "C:\Users\Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 294, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Users\Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import (
**ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser'** (C:\Users\Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\html\parser.py)
>>>
```

I've install and uninstall bs4 several times and still got the same error
what would you recommend?